# How to remove some number of files using a wild card before adding stuff back to them?

Tags: python-3.x, file, for-loop, wildcard, os.system

I have a set of `.txt` files named `my_file_1.txt, my_file_2.txt, ..., my_file_n.txt` where *n* is finite integer. As my python code is running (in a directory with path `~/simulation/some_code`), it is adding data into these files using the following `for loop`:

```
for realization in np.arange(1, n+1):
    # Identifying the file_path
    some_name = 'output/{}/Info/{}/{}/parameter_{:.3f}/my_file_{}.txt'.format(size, name, status, value, realization)

    # do some stuff

    with open(some_name, "a") as filename:
    print('{}'.format(some_list), file=filename)
    filename.close()
```

However, to begin with, these files are not empty and need to be emptied. To do so, I am running the following line ahead of time (in the home directory `~/` which is two levels up with respect to the directory of the above code) to make sure files are empty before being modified:

```
os.system('> output/{}/Info/{}/{}/parameter_{:.3f}/my_file_*.txt'.format(size, name, status, value))
```

While I expected to see * symbol should act as a wild card to empty all similar text files above, it seems that files are accumulating from previous data instead of removing initial data and adding the stuff above. Am I using * wild card incorrectly? Is this problem fixable without changing the path of my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the wildcard is correct. The mistake is with redirection. By default you only redirect (>) to one output. You can use the program `tee` to redirect std out to multiple other files like this:

(echo -n, echoes nothing)

`echo -n | tee *`

The pipe `|` passes the stdout of echo -n to the stdin of tee.
Then the wildcard will expand to all files in the directory.

`echo -n | tee my_file_1.txt, my_file_2.txt, ..., my_file_n.txt`

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, Interesting! So this last line you wrote is supposed to replace my last line above (in the same directory)?

Comment: Yes you have a lot going  on there path wise but something like:
`os.system('echo -n | tee output/{}/Info/{}/{}/parameter_{:.3f}/my_file_*.txt'.format(size, name, status, value))`